# Run [[processors.regex]] over multiple measurements

Tags: telegraf, telegraf-plugins

Is it possible to run the regex preprocessor over multiple measurements like that?

```
[[processors.regex]]
  namepass = ["measure1", "measure2"]

[[processors.regex.fields]]
    key = "agent"
    pattern = '^.*$'
    replacement = "NORMAL"
    result_key = "agent_type"
```

In my case two measurements both have an Access-Log as source (`[[inputs.tail]]`) but I want to keep them seperate as I want to compare both eventually.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: I'm not sure if this is how it's meant to be but a quickfix would looke like that:

```
[[processors.regex]]
  namepass = ["measure1"]

[[processors.regex.fields]]
    key = "agent"
    pattern = '^.*$'
    replacement = "NORMAL"
    result_key = "agent_type"

[[processors.regex]]
  namepass = ["measure2"]

[[processors.regex.fields]]
    key = "agent"
    pattern = '^.*$'
    replacement = "NORMAL"
    result_key = "agent_type"
```

Unfortunately it contains duplicated code which is bad.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you did this way. The configuration you mentioned in the question would have worked fine.

Comment: Well obviously it didn't work out for me which is why I had to use this dirty quickfix. I wonder why the first config didn't work too.